# How to fetch file icons of any files in OS X using Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, icons

I am writing a Mac app in which I list directory contents i.e. files /folders in that directory.

Now, I want to show thumbnails of the various file types of that directory. Files can be image files, pdf, psd, etc.

How do I fetch icons of any file type in Cocoa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application bundle usually has icons in a file that vary in size, so we can specify which version of the icon we require. For example

```
const int size = 64;
const char* filePath = "pathToFileOrAppBundle";

NSString* nsfilePath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:filePath];
NSImage *image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:nsfilePath];

// set the image size
[image setSize: NSMakeSize(size,size)];
```